# Minimum level in a tree in Common lisp

Tags: list, tree, lisp, common-lisp, min

I'm trying to write the code to find the minimum level in a tree (minimum number of nested sublists kinda)
The tree is given like this:

```
(A (B (E (I))(F))(C (G))(D))
```

which would look like:

```
      A
   /  |  \
  B   C   D
 /\   |   
E  F  G   
|
I
```

Which would result... level 1. Max level is level 3 but I just need the minimum level.

I tried using the min function but whatever I do, it will either return 1 or 0 cause if the list is null, I return 0 and min (0 or anything) is always 0. Any ideas how to solve this without mapping/lambda funct?

I tried doing something like this:

```
(defun nrlevels (tail)
  (cond
    ((null tail) 0)
    ((listp (car tail))
     (min (+ 1 (nrlevels (car tail)))
          (nrlevels (cdr tail)))) 
    (t (nrlevels (cdr tail)))))
```

But as I said, that min will get to compare (Eventually) something with 0 and 0 being the minimum, the end result will be 0. I don't know how to escape this loop.

Comment: "without mapping/lambda funct" that's in theory impossible, because it would mean without any function at all. Either way, it's an ... odd ... restriction.

Comment: I edited the problem with what I have so far and why it's not working properly

Comment: Why don't you use the function `minlevel` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34234127/2382734) to your previous answer?

Comment: Honestly I wanted to see if there's a way to make it shorter. Instead of 2 functions, to have only one that would just call itself, if it makes any sense.

Comment: what language is 'C-lisp'?

Comment: why don't you call it Common Lisp then?

Comment: cause here on stack I've seen it called clips/c-lisp and I thought this is the convention

Comment: I think that the correct way of posing this question is to link your old question, and say explicitly that you are trying to solve the problem with a single recursive function (and I think too that it is important to explain *why* you need this kind of solution, since it seems too contrived as requirement).

Comment: But I feel like this a totally different problem. People might look for this exact function online. It can be used on many problems, not only the tree balancing one.And I posted it out of curiosity. I tried to come up with a solution since last night and no good idea and people here like challenges so I said why not

Comment: @Melye77 `clisp` is an implementation of the language `Common Lisp`. Just to clarify the different tags ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting both the level recursion and the recursion that represents iteration over the children of a node into a single recursion.  The problem is to distinguish between visiting nodes having no children and having reached the end of a children list.

You need to separate these things.  I find it easiest to put the iteration over the children list into a `loop`:

```
(defun minimum-child-level (tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      0
      (1+ (loop :for child :in tree
                :when (listp child)
                :minimize (minimum-child-level child)))))
```

or `reduce`:

```
(defun minimum-child-level (tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      0
      (1+ (reduce #'min
                  (mapcar #'minimum-child-level
                          (remove-if-not #'listp tree))))))
```

*EDIT:* You could do it by interpreting a *min* accumulator and recursing one or the other way, but I do not recommend this for production code:

```
(defun minimum-child-level (tree &optional min-so-far)
  (cond ((endp tree)         ; end of child list
         (if min-so-far
             (1+ min-so-far) ; there were children
             0))             ; no children
        ((atom (first tree)) ; ignore symbols, go to next child
         (minimum-child-level (rest tree) min-so-far))
        (t                   ; sublist
         ;; recurse into child
         (let ((child-minlevel (minimum-child-level (first tree))))
           ;; go to next child
           (minimum-child-level (rest tree)
                                (if min-so-far
                                    (min min-so-far child-minlevel)
                                    child-minlevel))))))
```

Comment: It can't be done with recursive and just basic structures? No map functions/loops/atom/reduce ?

Comment: Done. <!-- Comments must be at least 15 characters in length. -->